# Joomla 2.5.16 take up to 2min to load

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

A relative asked me to fixed a `Joomla` website `(v2.5.16)` who has been hacked last year, probably due to lack of update **(is up to date now)**, unfortunately I have no information about this. The issue is that the `front end` take `2~ min` to load. The administration is loading normally so whatever the issue is, it depend of the `front end`. I already disabled all `modules` one by one and switched the `template` with another one to make sure that the`bug` is not in template or `plugins` folders, without success.

I must add that the problem is "probably" more recent than the hack, according to this person. So maybe there was a `script` somewhere reaching a random server which may not work anymore.

**PS :** the website is on a shared hosting. I have the `FTP` access but no `ssh`.

I know that I don't give any details which can lead to resolve this, but I need more a method to track what can go wrong and where than a solution.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: so what is your question? and what you had try so far?

Comment: I want to solve it, what I want to know is what can I do to find the origin of the issue. For the pro joomla, it might be simple if you know where to look and how to debug this

Comment: First thing you may want to do is update to Joomla 2.5.28. Being on an old version is the reason the site was hacked

Answer (score 1):

We have written a lengthy post explaining why a website might be slow: http://www.itoctopus.com/20-questions-you-should-be-asking-yourself-if-your-joomla-website-is-slow

From the looks of it, it might that the website is still hacked. Try overwriting the Joomla files with a fresh Joomla install and see if that addresses the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this issue will probably involve some or all of the following:

- updating Joomla and all third party extensions to the latest versions
- checking for and fixing malicious files using http://myjoomla.com or
  https://sucuri.net or similar
- analysing the performance of the website using http://gtmetrix.com
  (it's free) or similar to pinpoint and fix what is taking the most time to
  load

If the website has been hacked, you may need to reset passwords etc once the malicious files have been removed. See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/180/120 for more information about securing the website once it is fixed.